# Free HBITMAP from c++ in c# sent by PostMessage

Tags: c#, c++, wndproc

I have a memory problem caused by HBITMAP inside a struct sent from a callback by `PostMessage`.

.

I have a c++ callback that send a struct to c# using PostMessage. This look like this:

```
HRESULT CALLBACK MyCallback(void* ref, HRESULT hr, LPCWSTR pszMessage) {
   MyStruct st;        
   System::String^ serial = gcnew System::String(pszMessage);
   serial = serial->Substring(0, serial->LastIndexOf("\\"));
   serial = serial->Substring(serial->LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
   st.serial = StringToInt(serial);
   HBITMAP send = updatePreview(pszMessage);
   IntPtr ptr=(IntPtr) send;
   st.imagen = ptr;
   PostMessage(w, WM_UPDATE_PREVIEW, IMAGE_UPDATE, (LPARAM)&st);
}
```

This is my struct:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    IntPtr imagen;
    Int32 serial;
};
```

I receive this message in my c# code in my override WndProc:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == AePhocus.AePhocusManager.WM_UPDATE_PREVIEW)
    {
         PICTURE_STRUCT imageinfo = new PICTURE_STRUCT();
         Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, imageinfo);
                ....
                ....
     }
}
```

This method refresh my previews and work fine but the problem is that i can't free the HBITMAP sent from c++. If i destroy the pointer after PostMessage them the image received is Null but if i don´t destroy it the use of memory increase with each preview.

Could someone help me with this problem please?
Ty all!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i free hbitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944048/how-can-i-free-hbitmap)

Comment: no its a duplicated. In this post he need delete HBITMAP in C++ , in my case i can`t doing it.

Comment: You need to delete it in C++? Not in C# like the answer to the question I linked?

Comment: Zharios can you clarify what you're asking for? Your question title says "Free HBITMAP from c++ in c#"

Comment: @john i check your Posible duplicate message and the problem is similar but not exact the same. I my case the HBITMAP is inside a Struct that i trabsform to a c# struct with ` Marshal.PtrToStructure`. I ttry aply the post solution with a IntPtr to struct and does nothing.

Comment: You must use SendMessage().  And you need to release the HBITMAP when your code (or UI, presumably) no longer uses it.  You did not tell us how you use it, a random guess is that you'll want to pinvoke DeleteObject in a FormClosed event handler.  Also when you get another message.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot!!! this was my problem. Please put the answer and i get your points.

Comment: I'm just guessing, not enough info.  Please use what you've learned to complete the Q+A you started.  Post the solution and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PostMessage()` is asynchronous. By the time the receiving `WndProc` is called, the original `MyStruct st` variable is already gone from memory, and the `WndProc` is accessing garbage. You need to use `SendMessage()` instead to ensure the struct stays alive until after the `WndProc` exits.

As for freeing the `HBITMAP`, the correct way is to use [`DeleteObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183539.aspx), assuming the `HBITMAP` is not being passed across process boundaries.